# public nested classes inheriting from protected nested classes?

Tags: c++, public, protected, nested-class

In order to implement my own iterators, I would like to implement something like this :

```
class MyClass :
{
    public:
        class MyIterator1 {;};
        class MyIterator2 {;};
        class MyIterator3 {;};
};
```

As these iterators will share some common behaviours, it will be better if they inherit from a base iterator called `MyBaseIterator`. But I consider `MyBaseIterator` as a detail of implementation : the user should not use `MyClass::MyBaseIterator` directly. Is the following OK :

```
class MyClass :
{
    protected:
        class MyBaseIterator;
    public:
        class MyIterator1 : public MyBaseIterator {;};
        class MyIterator2 : public MyBaseIterator {;};
        class MyIterator3 : public MyBaseIterator {;};
};
```

Will the member derived from `MyBaseIterator` be available to the user even if `MyBaseIterator` is protected ?

Comment: what collection type you're creating so that you require three diff iterators in one class ? 0o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unless the user extends `MyClass`. To completely deny access, make it private. Also, not that you can only do anything meaningful with `MyBaseIterator` inside the class (guess you already know that).

Also, to completely hide implementation details, you should look into the **pimpl idiom**.